# What are the advantages of switching to Emacs for TeX/knitR work?

Tags: emacs, editors, r, knitr

Currently, I am using TeXStudio. Now, I am considering to switch to Emacs because I heard that is has its advantages when it comes to R and knitR. But what are the specific advantages? Yet, I am still struggling if switching is worth compared to the steep learning courve. (Yes, I am aware of the general TeX editor comparation thread.)

Comment: To put it simply, the switch is worth it.  Inline evaluation of R code is a big one.  I've heard `Emacs Speaks Statistics` (ESS) is *really* good.  See [r](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) and [ess](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ess) on Emacs.SE.

Comment: I can't answer about `R` and `knitR` since I've never really used them. (I once tried to use R to make a wordcloud, but had to give up because I had other things which actually needed doing.) But `emacs` doesn't have a *steep* learning curve (for LaTeX) so much as an infinitely long one. Remember: at the end of the day, your `.tex` file is just plain text, so you can just type it in.  That said, five years down the road with `emacs` and you'll still be learning things that you subsequently won't want to live without.

Comment: I switched to Emacs [three years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396967/emacs-what-are-good-tactics-for-navigating-directories-and-opening-files) and I never looked back. I use it mostly for R with ESS, which works really well and the very occasional bit of TeX. Emacs wasn't as horrible as I had been led to believe and it really is infinitely expandible. Packages like `ace-jump` and `Keychord` are great.

Comment: As someone who's been using emacs for about five years (coincidentally), I can confirm that this is true.  You can amass [a lot of tools to help you out](http://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/2tzk1f/how_do_you_use_latex_here_is_my_workflow/co492uk) over the years.

Comment: I found a nice starter kit here...http://kieranhealy.org/resources/emacs-starter-kit/ ... unfortunately, it's installation instructions are for mac only. Does anyone have an idea how to apply this on a windows machine?

Comment: Jens, try Vincent Goulet's distribution of the latest Emacs (for Windows) complete with ESS and AucTeX, which can be found [here](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/). This is how I started with Emacs.